XAML designer disappear when I close my project
I have a problem with a project I am cloning to edit. When I clone it and the open it, all my xaml files are displayed half code, half interface designer.
half code, hald designer image
But once I close it and re-open it, the designer part is no longer there and I can't figure out how to display it again
just code image
I already tried to go in Tools>Options>XAML Designer and tick "Enable XAML Designer", but it doesnt work :/
If someone has an idea, it would be cool
Thank you !
Edit : I tried every possible solution from the following questions : XAML Designer not showing up but it doesn't work

You could try pressing Shift+F7 to show the designer window.

Does this answer your question? XAML Designer not showing up
